# How to install OSSEC on virtual machine in azure

Tags: linux, security, azure, linux-on-azure, azure-cli

I want to install Open Source Host based Intrusion Detection System(OSSEC) on virtual machine of Linux Operating system in Azure .There is no proper documentation on How to install OSSEC in Azure. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the Azure Linux VM the same as your local machine. So you can install OSSEC in Azure Linux VM as you install it in your local Linux Machine. The installation [here](https://www.ossec.net/docs/manual/installation/installation-requirements.html#ubuntu) and choose which OS you need.